In Django, I would like to narrow a choice using a form to another form
I am trying to use the result of a selection as input to another selection. I have been working on this for three weeks, and I cannot find a simple answer.
Here are my models:
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class School(models.Model):

        id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
        school_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

        def __str__(self):
                return(f"{self.id} {self.school_name}")
                return self.id

        class Meta:
                ordering = ['id']
                indexes = [
                models.Index(fields=['id', 'school_name']),
                ]

class Courses(models.Model):

        id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=12)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        school = models.ForeignKey(School,  on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='school')
        name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
        cost = models.CharField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['id']
            indexes = [ models.Index(fields=['school']), models.Index(fields=['name', 'id'])]

        def __str__(self):
            return(f"{self.school} {self.name}")
            return self.name

class Student(models.Model):

        course = models.ForeignKey(Courses,  on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        student_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
        ordering = ['course']
        indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['course']),
             
        ]

And my views:
def choose_school3(request):
    
    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        aschool = Courses.objects.all()
        form=SelectSchoolForm(request.POST)
        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.is_valid():
                data = form.cleaned_data
                choice = data['school']
                selected_school = Courses.objects.filter(school=choice).values()
    
                context = {'choice': choice}
                return render(request, 'add_student2b.html', context)
        context = {'form': form, 'aschool':aschool}  
        return render(request, 'choose_school3.html', context)  
    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In To View Records!")
        return redirect('main')

def add_student2b(request, choice):

        chosen_school = Courses.objects.filter(school=choice).values()

        form = AddStudentForm(request.POST)
    
        context = {'form':form, 'choice':choice, 'chosen_school':chosen_school}
        return render(request, 'add_student2b.html', context)

def add_student5(request, pk):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        choice = School.objects.get(id=pk)
        courses = Courses.objects.filter(school=choice)
        
        form = modelformset_factory(Student, fields=['course','student_id'], formset=AddStudentForm2FormSet)

        context = {'courses':courses, 'choice':choice, 'form':form}
    
        return render(request, 'add_student5.html', context)

    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In To View Records!")
        return redirect('main')

The forms:
class SelectSchoolForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = Courses
            fields = ('school', )
            labels = {'school':'School', }
            widgets = {'school': forms.Select(attrs={"placeholder":"School", "class":"form-select"}),

             }

class  AddStudentForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
                model = Student
                fields = ( 'student_id', )
                labels = {'student_id':'',}
                widgets = {'student_id':forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Student ID", "class":"form-control"}),
               
                }

class AddStudentForm2FormSet(BaseModelFormSet):


            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

                super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
                self.fields['course'].queryset = Student.objects.filter(all)

and html:
choose_school3.html:
<form class="row g-3" action="{% url 'choose_school3' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="col-md-6">
    
    
    {{ form.as_p }}
    
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Choose School</button>

<a href="{% url 'school' %}" class="btn btn-success">Back</a>
</div>

</form>

add_student2b.html:
<form class="row g-3" action="{% url 'choose_school' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="col-md-6">
    
    
    {{ form.as_p }}
    
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">

<a class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" href="{% url 'add_student5' choice.id  %}" role="button">Add Student</a>

<a href="{% url 'school' %}" class="btn btn-success">Back</a>
</div>

</form>

and add_student5.html:
<form class="row g-3" action="{% url 'choose_school' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="col-md-6">
    
    
    {{ form.as_p }}
    
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">

<a class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" href="{% url 'add_student5' choice.id  %}" role="button">Add Student</a>

<a href="{% url 'school' %}" class="btn btn-success">Back</a>
</div>

</form>

Everything I try sends me to an error. This most recent incarnation gives me this:
cannot unpack non-iterable builtin_function_or_method object
referring to the {{ form.as_p }} tag. I've been going in circles and down rabbit holes. Is it possible to do this with Django (and without JS or other things) or not? Please help.
Update: I have been able to revise this a bit, and I think I'm getting close to the result I want. For those who don't completely understand what I'm trying to do, it is to have a user add a student with a course selection, but first the user must select a school on which the courses depend, in order to narrow down the available choices to a manageable number. I'll include the revised views and forms, and then state the current issue:
views:
     def choose_school7(request):
        aschool = Courses.objects.all()
        form=SelectSchoolForm(request.POST)
        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.is_valid():
                school = form.cleaned_data['school']
                messages.success(request, "School chosen    successfully!")

                return redirect('courses', school_id=school.id)

        context = {'form': form, 'aschool':aschool}  
        return render(request, 'choose_school7.html', context)


    def course_selection(request, school_id):

        form = SelectCourseForm(school_id, request.POST or None)
        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, "Record added successfully!")
                return redirect('school')
        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'course_selection.html', context)```

and forms

class SelectSchoolForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = Courses
            fields = ('school', )
            labels = {'school':'School', }
            widgets = {'school': forms.Select(attrs={"placeholder":"School", "class":"form-select"}),

             }

class SelectCourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
        def __init__(self, school, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['course'].queryset = Courses.objects.filter(school_id=school)
                        
        class Meta:
            model = Student
            fields = ( 'student_id', 'course')
            labels = {'student_id':'', 'course':''}
            widgets = {'student_id':forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Student ID", "class":"form-control"}),
                    'course':forms.widgets.Select(attrs={"placeholder":"Course", "class":"form-select"}),
          
           
            }


Currently it's failing with "AttributeError at /student/UoW

'SelectCourseForm' object has no attribute 'get'"

Due to my template invoking {{ form.as_p }}

I'm pretty sure this comes down to what I've done in this form, but I don't know what's wrong with it. Thanks.


ONE MAJOR FLAW is the return statements which don't make sense, since when a function hits a return statement, the rest of code after that inside the function will never be executed, so I strongly advise you to start again from ground and check your progress one at a time, otherwise I doubt you'll get an answer with your code like this. Good luck

I don't have code after my return statements, so your comment doesn't make sense to me. Unless you can point out a counter-example.

Where is the order of operation of the code?

Caveat: I don't really understand in detail what you are trying to do.
The simple answer is just two separate views implementing the first and second stages. Validation of the first causes a redirect to the second, which can receive the data from the first form through kwargs, or through the database if direct access to the second form has to be made securely impossible.
A more complex one is a form with hidden fields which you dynamically convert to non-hidden once the primary fields have been supplied and validated. One can also convert visible to hidden to preserve the contents.
I always use class-based views and recommend that everybody does. They hugely simplify the logic. For the previous,  one gets the initial values validated through the form, but form_valid then un-hides the hidden fields and returns form_invalid(self, form) until the extra information is supplied.
